# MVC3 & Razor - Change DateTime String from "mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM" to "mm/dd/yyy" in a Textbox

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textbox

I am trying to stop the Time from showing up in a Birthday Text Field that uses DateTime

My Code: (I'm using the Jquery DatePicker)

```
<label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
            @Html.TextBox("birthday", (Model.Birthday.ToString()), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker({ showOn: 'both', buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar-red.gif" });
});
```

I have the Model setup for the date:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
```

**Still the Text in the Text box displays:**

"8/21/2010 12:00:00 AM"

**I want Text in the Textbox to diplay as just:**

"8/21/2010"

**I have tried everything from:**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime>
```

but wont let me do that since I am @using a model

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use an editor template and data annotations on the view model to specify formatting which makes the views much cleaner:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Birthday:")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
```

and then inside your view:

```
<span class="datePicker">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Birthday)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Birthday)
</span>
```

and then adapt the selector because the textbox will no longer have the `datePicker` class:

```
$('.datePicker :text').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'both', 
    buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar-red.gif" 
});
```

Comment: You can also use `#Birthday` as a selector, afaik the Editor output will add an id with the property name.

Comment: @Filip, yes `#Birthday` could work but I don't like magic strings in the views because if I rename this property on my view model or I use this editor template somewhere deeper in the object hierarchy the id might also change to something like `#Root_Sub_Birthday`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I think this is a much better approach. I just pointed out that It is Possible.

Comment: very handy, thank you, just one question; what is the purpose of having an annotation that specifies the data type when it also forms part of the declaration? [DataType(DataType.Date)] and public DateTime?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to this:

`@Html.TextBox("birthday", (Model.Birthday.Value.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datePicker" })`

Since your DateTime is `Nullable` you need to do `.Value` before you can access the `DateTime` methods.

When calling `ToString` on a `DateTime` it will give you Date + Time. So Instead of calling `ToString` you want to use either [`ToString` with formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) or `ToShortDateString`.

MSDN has the following to say about [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

> The string returned by the
>   ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the
>   pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.
>   For example, for the en-US culture,
>   the standard short date pattern is
>   "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE culture, it
>   is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP
>   culture, it is "yyyy/M/d". The
>   specific format string on a particular
>   computer can also be customized so
>   that it differs from the standard
>   short date format string.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually running into this problem with Razor using MVC 3.  I ended up having to create a DateTime Partial Class in Shared/EditorTemplates to get the attributes I needed.

Previously my view was: `@Html.TextBoxWithAttributesFor(m => m.To, new { @class = "text-box", @readonly = "readonly" })` but this kept given me the TimeStamp.  Even when I tried .Value.DateTime or any other work around. But my current, working solution is:

view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.To)
```

partial class:

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "text-box", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I used this page as a second source:
http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Where you have "Model.Birthday.ToString()" you need to replace it with "Model.Birthday.ToShortDateString()"

Comment: What happened when you did? In which case, have you tried .ToString("MMddyyyy")

Comment: This does not seem to work with VB.NET. I get an error "Conversion from string "MMddyyy" to type integer is not valid. The weird thing is that it works fine with C#