# ASP.NET MVC 4 Forms Birthday box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I finding solution for may problem.

Is there something prepared for coder, It would solve to the award date of birth. For example, I have a small table with a calendar or a few dropdownlists (day, month, year).

Or I will must implement own.

Thanks for reply
PMilan

P.S.: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334761/birthday-dropdownlist-asp-net-c-sharp), but I would like find "kosher" solution.

Comment: explain more and brief to understand what you exactly want.

Comment: are you looking for a jquery datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything available in MVC that can act as a birthday picker right out of the box.

However, I would opt for using something like the [JQuery Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), rather than trying to write your own - there a literally thousands of implementations of the JQuery date picker out there.

If you're not looking to use any third party UI libraries, or you're trying to stick to basic web controls, you could do one of the following :

- Create a DateTime variable in your model, and decorate it as shown on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977543/mvc3-razor-change-datetime-string-from-mm-dd-yyyy-120000-am-to-mm-dd-yy)
- Use the cascading drop down approach. The user first selects a year, then they select a month, and then they select the day. You'll need to represent each of these with a separate variable in your model.